# Ubuntu won't boot beyond tty1 screen (with errors)

Tags: 15.04

I had upgraded to 15.04 few days back. Yesterday, I tried downloading a noobslab Mac theme and played and also changed the default graphic driver. Now, the GUI won't booot.

I have tried following methods that are not working:

1. `apt-get upgrade` - failed to fetch certain files
2. Tried installing xorg drivers. Won't work
3. Tried installing unity desktop and lightdm - xorg and amd 64.deb error
4. Tried to install Ubuntu desktop - still same failed to fetch error
5. Tried connecting to internet - couldn't.
   I had uninstalled network managed and added some other software. Sorry for being a noob but all my work is stuck. All help would be appreciated

After booting I get an emergency window

```
Errror 1 : Error getting authority.Couldn't not connect : no such file in the directory (g-io-error-quark, 1)
```

After <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> - Tty1 screen;
On `sudo apt-get update` I get following errors:

```
Err httpsz/archive.Ubuntu.com 'vivid-security(other names) Release.gpg
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.Ubuntu.com'

W: failed to fetch http://archive.Ubuntu.com/Ubuntu/dusts/vivid/Inrelease
```

On trying to install Ubuntu desktop

```
Following packages cannot be authenticated:
  Plymouth mountall libframe 6 ...a lot of xorg and xserver things
```

On further pressing yes I get such errors

```
E: failed to fetch "http://archive.Ubuntu.com/Ubuntu/main/x/xserver-xorg-video (and different errors)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your package system is broken

Download a new Sources List from here http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

delete your old sources.list

> sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list

Then copy the new one to

> sudo cp /"where ever you put the file"/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list

Then run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Hope this helps with your failed to fetch errors